# Problema para salvar com hibernate, tipo verificado é diferente do esperado

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou com um problema para salvar duas tabelas (`@OneToOne`) no banco usando o Hibernate. Usando entidades de relacionamento fraco (pessoa, endereço).

Erros apresentado no console:

> Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in public.citizen for column neighborhood_id. Found: int4, expected: bytea
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at zup.model.utils.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:29)
>       at zup.business.AbstractBusiness.save(AbstractBusiness.java:25)
>       at zup.business.CitizenBusiness.main(CitizenBusiness.java:131)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in public.citizen for column neighborhood_id. Found: int4, expected: bytea
>       at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:372)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1338)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:175)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:525)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
>       at zup.model.utils.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:25)

A minha classe modelo:

```
//pacote

//importações

//named queries

public class Citizen implements Serializable/*, Comparable<MessageModel>*/{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "citizen_cpf")
    private String citizen_cpf;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Size(min=3, max = 40, message = IMessages.SIZE_LIMIT_EXCEEDS)//detalhar o min�mo depois quando for tratar a inclus�o
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phone_number;


    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "city_name")
    private String city_name;


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //@OneToOne
    //@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Column(name = "neighborhood_id")
    private Neighborhood neighborhood;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="neighborhood_id")//chamando nesse atributo so valores da coluna neighborhood_id de outra tabela
    public Neighborhood getNeighborhood() {
        return neighborhood;
    }

    public Neighborhood setNeighborhood(Neighborhood n) {
        this.neighborhood = n;
        return neighborhood;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "street_name")
    private String street_name;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Column(name = "address_number")
    private int address_number;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Column(name = "home_address_geograpical_coordinates")
    private String home_address_geograpical_coordinates;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Column(name = "photo")
    private byte[] photo;

    public Citizen() {
    }

    //o construtor que eu estou utilizando para gerar meu objeto
    public Citizen(String city_name, String home_address_geograpical_coordinates, String citizen_cpf, String name, byte[] photo, String phone_number, String email, String street_name, int address_number) {
        this.citizen_cpf = citizen_cpf;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
        this.email = email;
        this.city_name = city_name;
        this.street_name = street_name;
        this.address_number = address_number;
        this.home_address_geograpical_coordinates = home_address_geograpical_coordinates;
        this.photo = photo;
    }
    //metodos privados
    //aqui ficaria todos os setters and getters

    //métodos sobrescritos
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (citizen_cpf != null ? citizen_cpf.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Citizen)) {
            return false;
        }
        Citizen other = (Citizen) object;
        if ((this.citizen_cpf == null && other.citizen_cpf != null) || (this.citizen_cpf != null && !this.citizen_cpf.equals(other.citizen_cpf))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "banco.Citizen[ CitizenId=" + citizen_cpf + " ]";
    } 
}
```

A segunda classe a que vai setar os valores como chave estrangeira na classe citada acima:

```
package zup.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import zup.messages.IMessages;

@Entity
@Table(name = "neighborhood")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Neighborhood.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Neighborhood c ORDER BY c.neighborhood_name"),
    //@NamedQuery(name = "Neighborhood.findByNeighborhoodId", query = "SELECT c FROM Neighborhood c WHERE c.NeighborhoodCPF = :NeighborhoodCPF"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Neighborhood.findByName", query = "SELECT c FROM Neighborhood c WHERE c.neighborhood_name = :neighborhood_name")})

public class Neighborhood implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //vari�veis e suas especifica��es
    @Id
    //@OneToOne( mappedBy="neighborhood_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "neighborhood_id")
    private int neighborhood_id;

    @NotEmpty(message = IMessages.NULL_FIELDS)
    @Size(min=3, max=60)//lembrando que nas especifica��es at� agora o m�nimo ainda n�o foi estipulado
    @Column(name = "neighborhood_name")//por conven��o estou colocando o valor que repassaram para o front-end
    private String neighborhood_name;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //metodos privados
    public String getNeighborhood_name() {
        return neighborhood_name;
    }

    public void setNeighborhood_name(String name) {
        this.neighborhood_name = name;
    }

    public int getNeighborhood_id() {
        return neighborhood_id;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //construtores
    public Neighborhood(){
    }

    public Neighborhood(String name){//lembrando esse construtor recebe apenas o nome porque o id � auto incrementado
        this.neighborhood_name = name;
    }
}
```

E a parte de teste que estou usando para testar as minhas inserções no banco:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    Neighborhood n = new Neighborhood("Carajás");
    String data = "ainda sem caminho para a foto";
    byte[] photo = data.getBytes();
    NeighborhoodBusiness nb = new NeighborhoodBusiness();
    nb.save(n);

    Citizen s = new Citizen();
    s.setNeighborhood(n);
    //int a = s.getNeighborhood().getNeighborhood_id();
    //System.out.println(a);
    //System.out.println("*-----------------------------*");
    Citizen c = new Citizen("Patrocínio", "b", "12345678912", "Rafael", photo, "34383156899", "hj@gmail.com",  "Avenida Brasil", 611);
    //Citizen c = new Citizen("12345678912", "Rafael", "34383156899", "lua@gmail.com", "Patrocínio", "Avenida Brasil", 611, "b", photo);

    CitizenBusiness cb = new CitizenBusiness();
    cb.save(c);
    System.out.println(cb.findByCPF("12345678912").getcitizen_cpf());
    System.out.println(cb.findByEmail("lua@gmail.com").get(0).getEmail());
    //System.out.println(cb.findBy("12345678912").getCitizenCPF());
    System.out.println(cb.findByName("Rafael").get(0).getName());
    //System.out.println(cb.findByCPF("12345678912").getCitizenCPF());  

}
```

Comment: Poste o código que você está fazendo pra salvar

Comment: Basicamente o erro diz que esperava `byte` e recebeu `int`

Comment: vou colocar por etapas e simplificar alguns pedaços que não são pertinentes

Comment: Passe as anotação que estão em `neighborhood` para `getNeighborhood()`, ou vice-versa. Este erro é por que `neighborhood` está sendo serializado e como é binário não há como persistir em tipo inteiro. Você deverá remover `@Column` de `neighborhood` também, ela não é usando em relacionamentos.